# Hide Field In Edit View Only (Need hook name)

Tags: drupal-7

I have added a field `field_shortform` to the basic page type and I wish to remove it if the node already exists (aka it shows up in Create, but not in Edit).  I am able to remove it with

```
$form['field_shortform'] = array();
```

however I need to figure out how to restrict this action to the node edit page only.  I tried using `_form_node_edit_form_alter` but that seems to have no effect...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the curse and beauty of posting to Stack Overflow is that regardless of how many hours I have spent searching for my answer, minutes after posting here I will magically stumble across it!

```
function MY_MODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    $node = $form_state['node'];

    if(isset($node->nid)){
        $form['field_shortform']= array();  
    }   
}
```

It was embarrassingly simple but I suppose too many hours in front of a small screen can make you a little simple :)